# Laravel : how to parse json in laravel view blade

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

i have json code in Laravel, how to parse in view blade?

my code :

```
$latitude1 = -7.325374900000001;    
        $longitude1 = 108.2251681;

        $latitude2 = -7.331842799999999;        
        $longitude2 = 108.2237382;

        $dataJson = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=".$latitude1.",".$longitude1."&destinations=".$latitude2.",".$longitude2."&key=".key);

        $data = json_decode($dataJson,true);
        $nilaiJarak = $data['rows'][1]['elements'][1]['distance']['text'];

        return view('maps', compact('maps','nilaiJarak'));
```

i want to only get distance on laravel view blade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the distance you need:

```
  $nilaiJarak = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```

or:

```
   $json = json_decode($dataJson);
   $nilaiJarak = $json->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text
```

Answer (score 1):

but you have parsed it already
in blade you can use `@php` `@endphp` tags
for example:

```
@php
    $data = json_decode($dataJson,true);
    $nilaiJarak = $data['rows'][1]['elements'][1]['distance']['text'];
@endphp
```

but you have to pass in blade `data` not `nilaiJarak`

```
return view('maps', compact('maps', $data));
```